# Generate a link to plain text version of email in html version of email

Tags: ruby

I want link "Click here" in html version of email.
After clicking link, it will redirect to plain text version of email.
How can we do that ?

I am using ruby.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post some code

Comment: An email client can't be redirected. You can show a plain-text version in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is impossible without using javascript. But js is disabled in email's html. Instead, you can try emulate the behavior you want by including multiple copies of the text further down in your email. For example:

```
<a href="#section1">Click here!</a>
<p>HTML content</p>
<h2 id="section1">Simple text</h2>
```